# What is an advisable temperature for drying sand in an oven, for later use as an epoxy filler?

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to dry some sand before I use it as an epoxy filler (making a machine base).  I would like the sand to be drier than when I started (so that I am not adding >=1% water that has condensed in a bag of sand to my epoxy mixture).  When the sand comes out of the oven and cools to ambient temperature it should have less water in it than when it started.

What temperature is advisable to heat the sand to given that it will cool back down to room temperature when I use it?

In chemistry I realize I might put the dried solid in an inert atmosphere or dry box. This is not possible here as it is for a home project. I am looking for some ball-park advice and rationale and realize that this is a complicated problem with a lot of variables.

[image]

Comment: My first reaction is "anything above 100C for a few hours" and then cover the bucket with something as it cools and until you use it. But common sense is often wrong...

Comment: Can it be in such a deep bucket?

Comment: A thin layer is several baking trays then seal in bags or similar with dessicant.

Comment: If can't do thin layer, you might need to mix to let the moisture actually escape

Comment: The bulk will take awhile to heat and dry and the difficult path will hinder vapor loss (thus the shallow tray comment). Drive nails thru (will likely self seal, minimally leaking sand) or solder them inside the bucket pointing to the center. The nails will conduct the heat deep into the sand when filled with sand and heated.

Comment: I was thinking mainly from the sides to the central axis, top to bottom of the sides.

Comment: A typical American pizza cooks at 425-deg F. Even 350-deg F is a low heat for a typical home oven. Temperatures in this range would probably be more efficient for driving out moisture. If you melt the sand, bucket, or solder it's probably a little higher than you need.

Comment: $$F = 9 * C / 5 + 32$$ $$C = 5 * (F - 32) / 9$$